# Blank nodes vs variables in SPARQL queries

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, virtuoso, blank-nodes

These two SPARQL queries result in different returns in [this SPARQL endpoint](https://libris.kb.se/sparql) (Swedish libraries). Why? I expected them to be functionally equivalent.

#### Query 1

```
PREFIX : <https://id.kb.se/vocab/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?language ?langName {
   [] :contribution [ a :PrimaryContribution ;
           :role rel:author ;
           :agent <https://libris.kb.se/qn247n18248vs58#it> ] ;
       :translationOf/a :Work ;
       :language ?language .
   ?language :prefLabel ?langName .

   FILTER(lang(?langName) = 'sv')    
}
```

#### Query 2

```
PREFIX : <https://id.kb.se/vocab/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?language ?langName {
   ?endeavor :contribution ?c .
   ?c a :PrimaryContribution ;
           :role rel:author ;
           :agent <https://libris.kb.se/qn247n18248vs58#it>.
   ?endeavor  :translationOf ?t .
   ?t a :Work ;
         :language ?language .
   ?language :prefLabel ?langName .

   FILTER(lang(?langName) = 'sv')    
}
```

My understanding of [4.14 Blank node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824925/the-difference-between-blank-nodes-and-variables-in-sparql-queries/21840361#21840361) is that blank nodes in queries act as variables. I've read this StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70812066/what-is-the-blank-nodes-utility-in-sparql-queries), and I know that two blank nodes in a SPARQL query need not reference the same node, but I do not think that is relevant in this case. Do you have any thoughts on the matter?

Answer (score 2):

The first has:

```
[] :translationOf/a :Work ;
   :language ?language .
```

The second has:

```
?endeavor  :translationOf ?t .
?t a :Work ;
   :language ?language .
```

The `:language` part is on different subject variables.

It is `[]` (corresponds to `?endeavor` in the second) in the first query and the object of `:translationOf` in the second.